# PHP acts different in IE and Chrome

Tags: php, sql-server

[SOLVED]

Problem solved.. It was a mistake in the PHP and from my side when testing the code. In chrome I entered a name that existed in the database. In IE I did not. Obviously, the statement returns false if no occurances of the name are found. A clumsy mistake made by me when porting code from one project to another. Should have checked more carefully. Sorry about that!

[ORIGINAL POST]

I have the following piece of code in my PHP-file:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE name='".$user."'")) > 0){
    //Do things
}
else{
    echo "Could not retrieve data from database!";
}
```

Now my problem is, that it works perfectly in chrome. The statement returns true. However in IE it returns false. I don't understand how this is even possible when PHP is a server-side scripting language.

Some information that might be of help:

- The PHP-file contains only PHP.
- The file is not run locally. It is located on a server.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's interesting! did you try to set: if (0). What do you get in IE then?

Comment: For your own good, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with PHP

Its most likely

- You page is somehow cached thus $user is not getting through.

Clear you browser cache to see if that works for you

Also beware the way you are running that query. you should me using mysql_real_escape_string to the very least to make that query safe

read this article on how to clear your browser cache

http://kb.iu.edu/data/ahic.html

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely something in your code, not your browser. The browser only outputs the HTML. Try using [var_dump($yourVariable)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to see what your variables are getting and to check on data type as well

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cache issue to me.  clear out your history.  Try a proxy for good measure such as hidemyass.com (in chrome and in ie).